# Mi form HTML se cierra solo

Tags: php, html, input

Mi form HTML  cierra automáticamente después de abrir con  dejando todos mis inputs fuera, ya busqué y busque y no veo el error, estoy trabajando con PHP sobre un modal.

```html
<tbody>                
          
      <?php
        $numeral = 0;
        while ($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {$numeral++;         
      ?>
        <tr>
        <form method="POST" action="funciones/actions.php">
              <th scope="row"><?php echo $numeral; ?></th>
              <td><?php echo $result['fullname']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $result['user']; ?></td>
              <td>
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></div>
                  </div>
                  <select class="custom-select" name="bandera">
                      <option value="1">Aceptar</option>
                      <option value="2">Denegar</option>
                  </select>
                </div>           
              </td>
              <td>
                  <div class="btn-group">
                    <input type="hidden" name="funcion" value="authorized">
                    <input type="hidden" name="registro" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-           placement="bottom" title="Validar Usuario">
                    <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
                    </button>                     
                  </div>
              </td>
          </form>
           </tr>
           
          <?php
           }
          ?> 
    </tbody>
```

Al ejecutarlo en el navegador cierra la etiqueta inmediatamente después de abrirla. Tal vez sea sencillo pero no encuentro el problema. ¿Qué puedo hacer para que no siga cerrando la etiqueta  antes de agregar los inputs?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que tu error es anidar el elemento form dentro del ciclo While{} Necesitas múltiples forms? o solo uno? Si sólo necesitas uno como cabe suponer debes abrirlo antes de While y cerrarlo luego de terminar el ciclo.

Comment: Si lees tu código pones un form en cada row y todos tienen el mismo action, bastaba uno solo. Ojalá anidando la tabla dentro del form. Personalmente no me gusta que el form quede anidado dentro del tbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un formulario no puede ser contenedor de filas o celdas, tienes que poner toda la tabla dentro del formulario o el formulario completo dentro de una celda, de lo contrario, tu HTML será incorrecto y el navegador tratará de corregirlo, por eso lo cierra.

La estructura de la tabla es muy específica y permite agrupar filas y celdas solo en contenedores adecuados, cualquier elemento que rompa esa estructura tendrá un funcionamiento de acuerdo a los "arreglos" que haga el navegador para tratar de mostrar un HTML correcto.

Algunos de esos errores son visibles sin inspeccionar:

```css
table {
  border:1px #000 solid;
  margin:20px auto;
}
form, .contenedor1 {
    display:block;
    min-height:30px;
    background:#ddd;
    border:1px #a00 solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
<form method="post" action="">
  <tr>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Texto1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Texto2"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar 1"></td>
  </tr>
</form>
  <tr>
  <form method="post" action="">
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Texto1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Texto2"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar 1"></td>
  </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td><form method="post" action=""><input type="text" placeholder="Texto1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="Texto2"></td>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Enviar 1"></form></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
<div class="contenedor1">
  <tr>
      <td>¿Qué pasó con el contenedor?</td>
      <td>Quedó antes de la tabla</td>
      <button>Botón fuera de la tabla</button>
  </tr>
</div>
</table>
```