# Me aparece una "s" en el dom pero cuando reviso el .html esa "s" no está. Ayuda

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel, materialize

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto, estoy usando materialize y laravel, en un titulo me aparece una "s" que no está escrita en el documento html, pero sin embardo, cuando lo miro en el inspector de elementos, si aparece, sin etiquetas ni nada, solo aparece suelta. Le adjunto fotos

[image: Este es el error que me aparece]

[image: Este es el inspector de elementos]

[image: Este es el documento html/php que estoy editando]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Por favor, cuando pongas código, no pegues screenshots, pega el texto. Prueba a eliminar la línea `<p> Historial Vehículos</p>` y ver si sigue apareciendo la s.

Comment: El error podría estar dentro de la tabla, aunque parezca extraño. Revisa esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376921/mi-form-html-se-cierra-solo/376954#376954