# ¿datatables, ciclo foreach php me crea divs vacios?

Tags: php, html, datatables

estoy usando un modal para mostrar datos de una bd, pero tengo un problema que se estan pintando divs vacios lo cual me esta generando un  espacio en la vista final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la ventana modal **codigos** he indentificado que si quito el bonto acciones, no se pintan esos divs,
tambien indentifique que la cantidad de divs corresponde a la cantidad de campos acciones, es decir tengo 100 registro cada uno con su campo acciones, asi msimo se esta pintando los divs vacios.

agrego mi codigo html donde muestro mi tabla, la verdad no sé que esta gerando que se pinte esos divs vacios.

pero sé que tienen que ver con el campo acciones.

1.porque los campos div tiene la misma clase del campo acciones, solo que no me pinta los botones:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
                           </div>
```

2. porque si elimino el campo acciones tambien se eliminan esos divs vacios.

AQUI otro ejemplo de que todo lo que este dentro de esa condicion se esta pintando arriba de la tabla:

```
echo '<tr class="fila-white">

                                            <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
                                            <td>'.$value["fecha_registro_to"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$value["cod_producto_to"].'</td>
                                            <td>'.$value["nombre_producto_to"].'</td>';


                                        if($usuarios2["tipo_usuario_pr"]=="PRODUCCION-ADMIN" || $usuarios2["tipo_usuario_pr"]=="DESPACHOS-ADMIN"){

                                                //ar_dump($usuarios2["tipo_usuario_pr"]);
                                           /*  echo
                                                '<div class="col-sm-3">
                                                    <td>
                                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
                                                            <button class="btn btn-warning btnEditCodigoPro manito-clic" editProducto="'.$value["id_producto_to"].'" ediCodigo="'.$value["cod_producto_to"].'" ediCodigoName="'.$value["nombre_producto_to"].'" idUsuario="'.$usuarios2["cod_persona_responsable_pr"].'" User="'.$usuarios2["usuario_pr"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarInsCnAvesEvac"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
                                                            <button class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarCodigoPro manito-clic" deleteProduct="'.$value["id_producto_to"].'" deleteCodigo="'.$value["cod_producto_to"].'" deleteCodigoName="'.$value["nombre_producto_to"].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </td>
                                                </div>'
                                            ; */

                                            echo ' como pueden ver si escribo algo en el campo acciones tAMBIEN SE PINTA RRIBA';

                                        }

                                        echo '</tr>';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**AQUI ESTA MI TABLA MODAL**

```
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

            <div class="modal-content">

                <!--****************************************************
                CABEZA DEL MODAL
                ********************************************************-->

                <div class="modal-header" style="background: #ff9595b4; color: rgb(255, 13, 13);">

                    <h4 class="modal-title text-center">CÓDIGOS</h4>

                </div>
    
                <!--****************************************************
                CUERPO DEL MODAL
                ********************************************************-->
    
                <section class="content">
    
                    <div class="box">
    
                        <div class="box-body">
    
                            <div class="row">
    
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label>AÑO:</label>
                                    </div>
    
                                    <select class="form-control input-sm" id="id_ano_searchCodPro">
    
                                        <?php
    
                                            $tabla=99;
                                            $item=99;
                                            $valor=null;
                                            $showadt = ControladorUserss::ctrshowdt($tabla, $item, $valor);
                                            //echo '<option value="">TODOS LOS REGISTROS</option>';
                                            foreach ($showadt as $key => $value) {
                                            echo '<option value="'.$value["list_fech"].'">'.$value["list_fech"].'</option>';
                                            }
    
                                        ?>
    
                                    </select>
                                </div>
    
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label>CÓDIGO:</label>
                                    </div>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="valorCodPro" placeholder="INGRESE CÓDIGO">
                                </div>
    
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                                        <label>NOMBRE:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" id="valorNameCod" placeholder="INGRESE NOMBRE">
                                </div>
    
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                                        <label>REFRESCAR:</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="button" class="input-sm btn btn-secondary manito-clic" id="boton_resetCodPro" style="width:90px;"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                                </div>
    
                            </div>
    
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="search_Codproducto" width="900px">
    
                                <thead>
    
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="width: 10px; color: #ed5249;">#</th>
                                        <th style="width: 166px; color: #ed5249;">FECHA REGISTRO</th>
                                        <th style="width: 50px; color: #ed5249;">CÓDIGO</th>
                                        <th style="width: 266px; color: #ed5249;">NOMBRE PRODUCTO</th>
                                        <?php
                                          if($usuarios2["tipo_usuario_pr"]=="USER-ADMIN" || $usuarios2["tipo_usuario_pr"]=="USER2-ADMIN"){
    
                                                echo
                                                    '<th class="text-center" style="color: #ed5249;">ACCIONES</th>'
                                                ;
    
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </tr>
    
                                </thead>
    
                                <tbody id="mostrarHOP">
    
                                    <?php
    
                                        $item = null;
                                        $valor= null;
    
                                        $Codigostb= ControladorTablas::ctrShowtbCodigo($item, $valor);
    
                                        foreach ($Codigostbas $key => $value) {
    
                                            echo '<tr class="fila-white">
    
                                                <td>'.($key+1).'</td>
                                                <td>'.$value["fecharegis"].'</td>
                                                <td>'.$value["codproduc"].'</td>
                                                <td>'.$value["nombreproduc"].'</td>
                                                ';
    
                                            if($usuarios2["tipo_user"]=="USER-ADMIN" || $usuarios2["tipo_user"]=="USER2-ADMIN"){
    
                                                echo
                                                    '<div class="col-sm-3">
                                                        <td>
                                                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
                                                                <button class="btn btn-warning btnEditCodigo manito-clic" editProducto="'.$value["id_prod"].'" ediCodigo="'.$value["codproduc"].'" ediCodigoName="'.$value["nombreprod"].'" idUsuario="'.$usuarios2["cod_peruserresp"].'" User="'.$usuarios2["user"].'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEditarCodigo"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Third group">
                                                                <button class="btn btn-danger btnEliminarCodigoPro manito-clic" deleteProduct="'.$value["id_prod"].'" deleteCodigo="'.$value["codproduc"].'" deleteCodigoName="'.$value["nombreprod"].'"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </td>
                                                    </div>'
                                                ;
    
                                            }
    
                                            echo '</tr>';
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
    
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn btn-closed manito-clic btnOcultarModal manito-clic center-block"><i class="fa fa-eye-slash"></i></button>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
    
    
                </section>
    
            </div>
    
        </div>
    
    </div>
```

Comment: quite el div que embuelve el td de los botones y tambien desaparecio este espacio, o los divs que se pintaban arriba, no entiendo porque tengo este problema, si tengo varias tablas similares y no he tenido ese tipo de problemas.

Comment: Lee [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376921/mi-form-html-se-cierra-solo/376954#376954) seguro te servirá para ver tu error.

Comment: si es correcto estaba colocando un div, donde no era necesario, con los td era suficiente.