# ¿Como actualizar datos de una tabla con un select y jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema al actualizar los datos de una tabla usando jquery y php, mi idea es que mediante un select puedas cambiar la información de una tabla, ya logre hacer esto, si tu seleccionas la opción 1 la tabla consulta los datos con ajax y php a mi base de datos y muestra la información en la tabla, el problema es que por cada fila de mi tabla se imprime un formulario para poder crear una función de modificar datos, el problema es que cuando carga la tabla por primera vez sin usar el select la función de modificar trabaja bien, me envía los datos por POST a otro archivo y me permite actualizar los datos, pero si actualizo la tabla con mi select los botones de modificar dejan de funcionar.

Esta es la forma en la cargo mi tabla por primera vez:

```
<div class="table-responsive-xl col-sm-12" id="panel">
            <table class="table" id="ingresos-tabla">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Fecha de pago</th>
                    <th>No. de recibo</th>
                    <th>Forma de pago</th>
                    <th>Poliza</th>
                    <th>Estatus</th>
                    <th>Fecha de emision</th>
                    <th>Empresa</th>
                    <th>Concepto</th>
                    <th>Partida</th>
                    <th>Mes</th>
                    <th>Distribución</th>
                    <th>Periodo</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="contenido">
                    <?php
                        foreach ($ingresosGeneral as $key => $value) {
                            echo "<form id='formularioIngresos' name='formularioIngresos' action='../editarIngreso' method='post'>";
                            echo "<input type='hidden' id='idRegistro' name='idRegistro' value='".$value['id_ingresos']."' />";
                            echo "<tr>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['id_ingresos']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['fecha_pago']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['no_recibo']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['forma_pago']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['poliza']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['status']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['fecha_emicion']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['empresa']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['concepto']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['partida']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['mes']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['distribucion']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['periodo']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['cantidad']."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$value['total']."</td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' id='btnModificar' name='editar' value='Editar'></td>";
                            echo "<td><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' id='btnEliminar' name='eliminar' onclick='eliminarFun()' value='Eliminar'></td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                            echo "</form>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
             </table>
        </div>
```

Mi select esta creado de esta forma:

```
<div class="form-group" id="select-banco">
              <label for="sell">Selecciona una cuenta:</label>
              <select class="form-control" id="sell">
                <option id="cuenta" value="0">Todas las cuentas</option>
                <?php

                    foreach ($cuentasGeneral as $key => $value) {
                        echo "<option id='cuenta' value=".$value['id_cuenta'].">".$value['banco']." ".$value['no_cuenta']."</option>";
                    }
                ?>
              </select>
            </div>
```

Cuando mi select cambia tengo una función en Javascript que consulta la información de la siguiente forma:

```
$("#sell").on('change',function(){
        var data= $(this).val();
        var busqueda = "busqueda="+data;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../modelo/cuentaID.php",
            data: busqueda,
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                $("#ingresos-tabla tbody").html(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

con la función

> $("#ingresos-tabla tbody").html(data);

muestro los nuevos valores de la consulta en mi tabla, pero el botón de modificar ya no funciona después de la actualización de datos.
La función devuelve la siguiente información:

```
foreach ($cuentas as $key => $value) {
                echo "<form id='formularioIngresos' name='formularioIngresos' action='../editarIngreso' method='post'>";
                echo "<input type='hidden' id='idRegistro' name='idRegistro' value='".$value['id_ingresos']."' />";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$value['id_ingresos']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['fecha_pago']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['no_recibo']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['forma_pago']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['poliza']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['status']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['fecha_emicion']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['empresa']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['concepto']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['partida']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['mes']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['distribucion']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['periodo']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['cantidad']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$value['total']."</td>";
                echo "<td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' id='btnModificar' name='editar' value='Editar'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='button' class='btn btn-danger' id='btnEliminar' name='eliminar' onclick='eliminarFun()' value='Eliminar'></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</form>";
            }
```

Comment: Puedes llamarme? te aydo a solucionarlo

Comment: Hola. El problema radica en que al actualizar la tabla los comportamientos de evento enlazados durante el proceso de carga inicial **no cobijan a los nuevos elementos**. La solución es simple: 1. Escribir una función que enlace todos los eventos necesarios. 2. Invocarla en document.onload() para tenerla activa en estado normal. 3. **Al terminar la recarga vía Ajax** antes de salir de **success:** invocar la función de enlace de eventos para que ligue los que fueron agregados.

Comment: Como en tu código no se ve como enlazas los eventos, ni pude identificar qué deja de funcionar no pude ofrecerte algo mejor que la idea anterior.

Comment: @quevedo deja intento con lo que mencionas en tu primer comentario, si no funciona agrego el código que me hace falta a la pregunta.

Comment: Aparte de que estás repitiendo ID de los botones en cada fila, tienes un HTML mal formado; te recomiendo leer [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/376921/mi-form-html-se-cierra-solo/376954#376954)

Comment: @Triby buena recomendación

Comment: @Triby Tenias razón, estaba mal formado el HTML, pero ya quedo arreglado.