# El browser me cierra automáticamente la etiqueta form dejando inputs por fuera

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, formularios, navegador-web

Tengo el siguiente problema. En una tabla que me trae registros de una BD en mysql en una de las celdas muestro un botón que me llama a una modal para editar el registro correspondiente (obviamente una modal por registro). La misma se muestra sin inconvenientes, pero el navegador me cierra la etiqueta form de la modal automáticamente dejando todos los inputs por fuera.

El resultado en el navegador es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Codigo de la Ventana Modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_editar_<?php echo $id; ?>" tabindex="0">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Edit Assignment <?php echo $vec[1]; ?></h3>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <form action="php/actualizaDatos.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                        <label style="font-weight: bold;">Agency</label>
                        <input class="form-control" list="agencyOptions" name="agency" placeholder="Select an Agency" value="<?php echo $agency; ?>">
                        <datalist id="agencyOptions">
                            <?php
                                $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM sw5hmgj4rwl_company WHERE type = 'Agency' ORDER BY name";
                                $agen = mysqli_query($link,$sql4);
                                while ($ag = mysqli_fetch_array($agen)) {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$ag[2].'"></option>';
                                }
                            ?>
                        </datalist><br>
                        <label style="font-weight: bold;">Appointment Date</label>
                        <input type="date" name="app_date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $vec[5]; ?>"><br>
                        <label style="font-weight: bold;">Scheduled Time</label>
                        <input type="time" name="sch_time" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $vec[6]; ?>"><br>
                        <label style="font-weight: bold;">Interpreter</label><br><br>
                        <input type="radio" name="cert" id="cert_yes" value="Yes">
                        <label for="cert_yes">Certified: Yes</label><br>
                         <input type="radio" name="cert" id="cert_no" value="No">
                        <label for="cert_no">Certified: No</label><br><br>
                        <input class="form-control" list="interpreterOptions" name="interpreter" placeholder="Select an Interpreter" value="<?php echo $vec[9]; ?>">
                        <datalist id="interpreterOptions"></datalist><br>
                        <label style="font-weight: bold;">Modality</label>
                        <select name="modality" class="form-control">        
                            <option selected value="<?php echo $vec[7]; ?>"><?php echo $vec[7]; ?></option>
                            <?php  
                                if ($vec[7] == 'On Site') { ?>
                                    <option value="Videochat">Videochat</option>
                            <?php 
                                }
                                else if ($vec[7] == 'Videochat'){ ?>
                                    <option value="On Site">On Site</option>
                            <?php       
                                }
                                else{
                            ?>
                                <option value="On Site">On Site</option>
                                <option value="Videochat">Videochat</option>
                            <?php        
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select><br>
                        <label style="font-weight: bold;">Videochat Link</label>
                        <input type="text" name="url" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $vec[10]; ?>">
                        <br>
                        <label style="font-weight: bold;">Provider</label>
                        <input type="text" name="provider" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $vec[8]; ?>"><br>
                        <label style="font-weight: bold;">Observations</label>
                        <textarea name="obs" class="form-control"><?php echo $vec[11]; ?></textarea><br>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer" align="right">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

---

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td><b>ID</b></td>
                <td><b>Operator</b></td>
                <td><b>Associated Assignment</b></td>
                <td><b>Agency</b></td>
                <td><b>Date</b></td>
                <td><b>Time</b></td>
                <td><b>Modality</b></td>
                <td><b>Provider</b></td>
                <td><b>Interpreter</b></td>
                <td><b>Videochat Link</b></td>
                <td><b>Observations</b></td>
                <td><b>Patient's List</b></td>
                <td><b>Edit</b></td>
                <td><b>Delete</b></td>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
                $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM sw5hmgj4rwl_groupal_assign";
                $result = mysqli_query($link,$sql1);
                while($vec = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

                    $id = $vec[0];
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $vec[1]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[2]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[3]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $agency; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $time; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[7]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[8]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $interpreter; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[10]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $vec[11]; ?></td>                
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-md" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal_editar_<?php echo $id; ?>">
                        <i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-lg"></i>
                    </button>
                </td>
                <?php 
                    include 'modal_editar.php'; 
                ?>
            </tr>
            <?php  
                }
            ?>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: El problema es exactamente el mismo de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/376921/54039) solo tienes que respetar la estructura de tablas. Por favor [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/520689/edit) para mostrar código como texto en vez de una captura de pantalla, debes incluir tanto la tabla como el formulario.

Comment: No me deja incluir código porque el código es muy extenso

Comment: No pongas todo, solo algunas filas de la tabla y la ventana modal, con su formulario.

Comment: Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y conseguir mejor ayuda. Tal como esta planteada tu pregunta no podemos ayudarte. Las preguntas han de ser autocontenidas. Puedes pulsar sobre el enlace [edit] que ves a pie de pregunta para agregar el código que has puesto en la sección de respuestas (y borrar estas después).